# can I manually run Docker containers on a Kubernetes node?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Is it *fine* with Kubernetes v1.10 if I manually run Docker containers on a Node, i.e. does Kubernetes just ignore them, and don't they cause any issues with the Scheduler if there are no conflicts (e.g. bound ports)?

Of course this is far away from any *best practice*, and should only be considered an interim solution while some containers are migrated to Kubernetes Pods.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, this is not best practice, but it is actually fine to run Kubernetes pods and Docker containers in parallel on the same node.